# Enable Sticky Behaviour of Electron App Notifications on Windows Platform

Tags: javascript, angular, notifications, electron, node-notifier

**I want to achieve the sticky behaviour of notifications in the electron desktop application until the user clicks on the notification itself.**

I am using **node-notifier** to achieve this behaviour following this [documentaion](https://github.com/mikaelbr/node-notifier) and using [ngx-electron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-electron) to use ElectronService for importing the main.js file in the angular component file.

Here is my **main.js** file:

```
const notifier = require('node-notifier')
exports.notifier = (msg) =>  {
  notifier.notify({
  title: 'Notify Me',
  message: msg,
  wait: true,
  timeout: 1500000,
  sound: true,
  icon:  './assets/images/logo.png'
});
```

**app.component.ts**:

```
import {ElectronService} from 'ngx-electron';
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public main_js : any;

  constructor(private _electronService: ElectronService ) { 
    this.main_js  = this._electronService.remote.require("./main.js");
    this.getTasks();
  }

  getTasks() {
    var message = 'New Task Assigned!!!';
    this.main_js.notifier(message);
  }
}
```

**Electron App Notification**:

[image: electron_notification]

Currently,I am checking this notification behaviour on Windows Platform and the notification remains sticky until and unless user takes any action including any key press from keyboard or any mouse movement.

**I want notification to stuck on the screen until the user clicks on close label of notification itself and not closes on clicking any other part of the screen.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I am not able to achieve the sticky behaviour of notifications in
electron. However, I have found an awesome alternative for that which is
combination of both [Electron_Tray](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/tray.md) and Node-Notifier
[Balloon_Notifications](https://github.com/mikaelbr/node-notifier#usage-windowsballoon).

The best part is that it works on both **Windows** and **Linux**
Platform like a charm eventually gives a **cross-platform** funtionality. I haven't tested it on mac yet ,may be it works
there as well. Here is my tested code:

**app.component.ts**

```js
import {ElectronService} from 'ngx-electron';
  @Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
  })
  export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    public main_js : any;

    constructor(private _electronService: ElectronService ) {
      this.main_js  = this._electronService.remote.require("./main.js");
      this.getTasks();
    }

    getTasks() {
      var message = 'New Task Assigned!!!';
      this.main_js.notifier(message);
  }
}
```

**main.js**

```js
let tray = null

function createWindow () {
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    icon: path.join(__dirname, 'dist/assets/images/logo.png')
  })

  // +++++++  TRAY NOTIFICATIONS  +++++++++ //
  var icon_tray = path.join(__dirname,'dist','assets','images','logo.png');

  tray = new Tray(icon_tray)

  const trayMenuTemplate = [
  {
    label: 'Maximize',
    click: function () {
      //For Maximizing the Window
      if(!win.isVisible()) { win.show() }
    }
  },

  {
    label: 'Minimize',
    click: function () {
      //For Minimizing the Window
      if(win.isVisible()) { win.hide() }
    }
  }]

  tray.setToolTip('I am Notifier!!!')
  let trayMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(trayMenuTemplate)
  tray.setContextMenu(trayMenu)
  tray.displayBalloon({
    title: 'Notifier Realm',
    content: 'Greetings!!!',
    icon: icon_tray
  });

  tray.on('click', () => {
    win.isVisible() ? win.hide() : win.show()
  })
}

exports.notifier = (msg) =>  {
// pops out the app window if minimized and show the notification 
  if(win.isVisible()){
    // win.hide()
  } else {
    win.show()
  }
  if(msg != undefined) {
    notifier.notify({
      title: 'Nethues Notify',
      message: msg,
      wait: true,
      icon:  './assets/images/logo.png'
    });
  }
}
```

Now, whenever the app window is minimized and a new task is assigned by
a different user, the window pops out above all the applications
(whatever is opened on your screen) and show the newly assigned task
notification to the user.

Comment: I have update the answer. May be it can help you know